# Regex raw query in PGAdmin vs Sequelize

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

Having constructed a query that does exactly what I expect in PGAdmin, the same as a raw query via Sequelize is returning zero results (not an error, just zero results).

The regexp is for returning only `orderNumber` records that contain a continuous string of numerals, nothing else.

PGAdmin:

```
select distinct on ("orderNumber") *
from public."Orders"
where "fromDomain" = '[an email address]'
and "orderNumber" ~ '^\d+$'
order by "orderNumber", "emailDate"
```

Sequelize:

```
const [results] = await db.sequelize.query(
    `SELECT
        DISTINCT ON ("orderNumber") *
      FROM
        "Orders"
      WHERE
        "fromDomain" = '[an email address]'
        and "orderNumber" ~ '^\d+$'
      ORDER BY
        "orderNumber",
        "emailDate"`
  )
  return results
```

Any ideas why the Sequelize version gives zero results when PGAdmin gives the correct 100+ records?

Comment: You might need to escape the `\ `  in the JavaScript string, e.g. `'^\\d+$'`

Comment: That was exactly it, thanks!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I was also having a similar issue and was very confused - thank you!